next in .lldb init enters to assembly
I often have to reenter the same steps when debugging a program with lldb so I decided to put them into an .lldbinit file:
file main
b ft_printf
run
next

I should automatically load the file, set a breakpoint, run the program and go to the next line. Instead I get his output:

Current executable set to '/Users/baschnit/repos/42printf_new/easytest/main' (x86_64).
Breakpoint 1: where = main`ft_printf + 312 at ft_printf_bonus.c:74:8, address = 0x0000000100002578
Process 33829 launched: '/Users/baschnit/repos/42printf_new/easytest/main' (x86_64)
Process 33829 stopped

thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = instruction step over
frame #0: 0x0000000100011025 dyld_dyld_start + 37 dyld_dyld_start:
->  0x100011025 <+37>: movq   -0x8(%rbp), %rdi
0x100011029 <+41>: cmpq   $0x0, %rdi
0x10001102d <+45>: jne    0x10001103f               ; <+63>
0x10001102f <+47>: movq   %rbp, %rsp
Target 0: (main) stopped.
Process 33829 stopped
thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = instruction step over
frame #0: 0x0000000100011025 dyld_dyld_start + 37 dyld_dyld_start:
->  0x100011025 <+37>: movq   -0x8(%rbp), %rdi
0x100011029 <+41>: cmpq   $0x0, %rdi
0x10001102d <+45>: jne    0x10001103f               ; <+63>
0x10001102f <+47>: movq   %rbp, %rsp
Target 0: (main) stopped.


Why does it show me the assembly code and not the line info?
When I set the config file to the following
file main
b ft_printf
run

and start lldb with lldb and enter next by hand, the output is the following:

Current executable set to '/Users/baschnit/repos/42printf_new/easytest/main' (x86_64).
Breakpoint 1: where = main`ft_printf + 312 at ft_printf_bonus.c:74:8, address = 0x0000000100002578
Process 34414 launched: '/Users/baschnit/repos/42printf_new/easytest/main' (x86_64)
===== my =======
Process 34414 stopped

thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
frame #0: 0x0000000100002578 main`ft_printf(format="%%") at ft_printf_bonus.c:74:8
71           int                     written_bytes;
72
73           // printf("\nstart with format: %s\n", format);
-> 74           if (!*format)
75                   return (0);
76           specs = NULL;
77           get_specs_str_from_format_str(format, &specs);
Target 0: (main) stopped.


How can I use the next command in the config file without seeing assembly code but the line info?

The issue isn't that lldb is "showing you disassembly" but rather in the first case, the "run" command seems to have stopped very early in the dynamic loader code, and then the next turned into a next-instruction because you were in code with no debug information.  Execution hasn't gotten to user code yet.I couldn't reproduce the behavior you showed with both simple and complex debuggee's.    Maybe file an issue with the llvm project issues tracker: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues.
